# Can I insert executable PHP code into Joomla custom HTML module?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

if you open this Joomla website you can easy understand what I have to do: http://lnx.erusma.org

As you can see at the bottom of the page there is a **Custome HTML Joomla module** named **Get in touch**

This custom HTML module contains this simple HTML code that show an e-mail form:

```
<form>
    <input id="name" title="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" size="23" style="width:94%" />
    <input id="email" title="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" size="23" style="width:94%" /> <br />
    <input id="subject" title="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" size="51" style="width:94%" /><br />
    <textarea id="message" cols="33" style="width:94%" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <a style="display:inline-block;background:#fff;border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;border-bottom: 2px solid #93B62A;padding:8px 12px;" href="#" style="float: left;">Submit</a>
</form>
```

I have inserted this HTML code by the **JCE Joomla Text Editor**.

Now I want to do the following thing: I have to attach to this form a php script that sends an email to a certain address (sending the name of the sender, the e-mail of the senter, the subject o the message and the text of the message)

Can I put this executable PHP script into the **JCE Joomla Text Editor**? It seems to me that have some problem to do it but I don't know if am I missing something.

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: I don't know why you didn't download a contact form extension from the Joomla Extensions Directory which would have used proper Joomla standards. I would not recommend inserting it using the editor and calling a custom php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an module to do your job and not a html form via  JCE Joomla Text Editor.

But if you want keep like that then you must replce `<form>` with below code

```
<form action='index.php?option=com_GetInTouch' method="get">
```

and after that you must develop your own custom joomla `component` named `GetInTouch` . 
Read this artiche about how can create custome `component` for `joomla 2.5`
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Comment: I wouldn't say a form this small requires a component

Comment: The easy way is use a module for this job, check this link http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms/16802 or google it like joomla (your joomla version) contact form module

Answer (score 1):

JCE Editor will strip non-HTML code when saving your Custom HTML Module.

You can use a plugin such as Sourcerer or similar and include your code within {source}{/source} tags so that the code is preserved.

Sourcerer: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free version of sourcerer.

This article explain how to use this plugin
https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/use-javascript-or-php-in-a-joomla-article/#!/ccomment-comment=1408

Step #1. Download the Sourcerer Plugin
Go to the Joomla Extensions Directory and find Sourcerer.
[image]

Step #2. Upload and Install Sourcerer
In the Administrator area of your Joomla site, click Extensions > Manage. You will be taken to the Extensions: Install administrative page:
go to extensions manage

Click Upload Package File tab.
Click Or browse for file green button and find the Sourcerer plugin installation file on your hard drive.
Click twice on the plugin package file name to start its installation.
Go to Extensions > Plugins. and make sure the following plugins are enabled:
Button - Regular Labs - Sourcerer
System - Regular Labs - Sourcerer

Step #3. Add JavaScript and PHP codes to a Joomla Article
go to articles add new article

Click Content > Articles > Add New Article.
Click on the new Code icon at the TinyMCE editor toolbar.
[image]

You will see Insert Code popup.

[image]

Write your code directly into the box. Make sure that code has the normal opening and closing tags.

[image]

When you're done, click Insert in the top-left corner.
click the insert button

Click Save or Save & Close.
Now check this article at your site frontend. You should see your JavaScript and PHP code snippets at work.
[image]

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and see if you can help us there as well.